# problema con duplicidad de informacion al abrir una modal

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal

Buenas noches tengo un problema cuando voy a insertar un comentario a un reagistro ya hecho tengo q abrir una modal.. en ella la primera vez aparece *agregar comentario a : "nombre de usuario"...* pero si cierro y vuelvo abrir la modal ella me dublica el nombre de usuario y asi sucesivamente ...

*agregar comentario de rechazo a : luis* *agregar comentario de rechazo a : luisluis ... y se va avregando el nombre cada vez q cierres y abras la modal

funcion de js para que aparesca el nombre es :

```
 $('#motivo_del_rechazo').click(function (ID_SOLICITUD){

   var login;
    var id_solicitud;
   
    
    $.map( 
 $('#table_solicitudes_usuario').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), 
 function (row) {
        login = row.LOGIN;
        id_solicitud = row.ID_SOLICITUD;
        
    });
    if(!login){
        swal({title: "Advertencia",text: "Debe seleccionar una solicitud y agregar un comentario para poder rechazar ",icon: "warning"});  

    } else {


          $("#titulo_rechazo").append(login); // con esta funcion mostramos el nombre en la modal

      $('#modal_rechazo').modal('show'); 

            
            }
    

 });


<div class="modal fade" id="modal_rechazo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
 labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo_rechazo">Agregar Comentario Rechazo a  : </h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      


      <div class="form-group">
        <form role="form" id="form_rechazo">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Indique el comentario :</label>
        </form>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comentarios">


      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="rechazar_solicitud">Aceptar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

como pueden ver el nombre *titulo_rechazo* utilizado en el js esta en el *id del h5* y o que necesito es que aparesca una sola vez independientemente se cierre o abra la modal 10 veces

tambien necesito que al enviar el comentario de la modal se borre lo escrito en la caja de texto

```
$("#modal_rechazo").find('form')[0].reset();




    function recha_usuario(){
       
    var login;
    var id_solicitud;
    var NOMBRE;
    var comentario =$("#comentarios").val();
    var LOGIN;

    $.map( $('#table_solicitudes_usuario').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
        login = row.LOGIN;
        id_solicitud = row.ID_SOLICITUD;
        NOMBRE = row.NOMBRE;
        comentarios = row.comentarios; 

    });
    if(!comentario){
        swal({title: "Advertencia",text: "No deje campo vacio.",icon: "warning"});  
    } else {

            swal({
               
                title: "informacion",

                text: "¿Desea rechazar la solicitud de : "+login+" ?",

                icon: "info",

                buttons: {cancel: true, confirm: true, confirm: true, 

                cancel: {text: "Cancelar",visible: true}},

            })


        .then((confirm) => {
            if (confirm) {
               var mensaje = '';
                $.ajax({
                    timeout: 120000, 
                url:"controlador_usuario/user_informacion",
                type:"post",
                datatype:"json",
                data:{'login':_user_login_ }, 
                error: function(jqXHR) 
                {
                    var error = error_ajax(jqXHR);

                },
                success:function(user_info){
                    var usuarioEliminar = JSON.parse(user_info);
                   
                    var login_solicitante = $.map( $('#table_solicitudes_usuario').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {return row.USER_SOLICITUD});
                    var nombre_solicitante = String($.map( $('#table_solicitudes_usuario').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {return row.nombre_solicitante}));
                   

            mensaje += '<table>';
            mensaje += '<tr>';
            mensaje += '<th colspan="3"><b>Datos: </b></th>';
            mensaje += '</tr>';

            mensaje += '<tr>';
            mensaje += '<td style="width:50%"><b>Login solicitado por el sistema:</b></td>';
            mensaje += '<td><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;"><b> </b>'+login+'</p></td>'; 
            mensaje += '</tr>';

            mensaje += '<tr>';
            mensaje += '<td style="width:25%"><b>Comentario:</b></td>';
            mensaje += '<td><p style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;">'+comentario+' </b></p></td>';
            mensaje += '</tr>';

           
             mensaje += '</table>';
                    NOMBRE = usuarioEliminar.NOMBRE
                    LOGIN  =usuarioEliminar.LOGIN



                    $.ajax({
                    timeout: 30000, //30 segundos
                    url:"Usuarioscontroller/rechazarUsuario",
                    type:"post",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data:{
                        'NOMBRE' : NOMBRE,
                        'id_solicitud': id_solicitud
                        'comentario': comentario,
                    'LOGIN': LOGIN
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR){
                       
                        var error = error_ajax(jqXHR);

                    },
                   success:function(rechazarUsuario){
                        if(rechazarUsuario){
                            if(rechazarUsuario == 1){
                                swal({title: "Éxito",text: "Solicitud de usuario rechazada.",icon: "success"});
                                $("#modal_rechazo").modal("hide");
                                update_solicitudes_pendientes(); 

                                $.ajax({
                                        timeout: 120000, //30 segundos
                                        url:"Usuarioscontroller/correo_rechazo_usuario",
                                        type:"post",
                                        datatype:"json",
                                        data:{'mensaje': mensaje, 'cc_solicitante': correo_solicitante
                                    }, 
                                        error: function(jqXHR) 
                                        {
                                            var error = error_ajax(jqXHR);

                                        },
                                        success:function(mail_rechazar_usuario){
                                        }
                                    });    
                                }else{
                                    swal({title: "Error",text: "Hubo un problema al realizar la solicitud.",icon: "error"});
                                    $("#modal_rechazo").modal("hide");
                                    $("#modal_rechazo").find('form')[0].reset();

                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    });      
                }
            });                                
            return true;
        }else{
            swal("Error", "Captcha invalido", "error");
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu javascript está lleno de errores de cierre de llaves y paréntesis. Te recomiendo que lo revises primero, asi no se puede ayudar. Recuerda crear un [ejemplo válido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: bueno hay lo coloque completo y esta funcional

Comment: Aquí te falta una coma al final:  `'id_solicitud': id_solicitud`

Comment: ¿Y esto esta bien?  `buttons: {cancel: true, confirm: true, confirm: true, cancel: {text: "Cancelar",visible: true}},`   Veras, lo primero que hago cuando pegais el código es ponerlo en https://jsfiddle.net/, en casilla del javascript, y alli me aparecen esos errores... te recomiendo que hagas lo mismo hasta que no te salga ninguno

Comment: si eso esta bien esis botones son del alerta que se coloca en el codigo , el codigo lo estoy compilando y todo va bien ... solo me falla en lo que coloque en la imagen ... el nombre se va agregando al lado de Agregar comentario de rechazo :xxxx

Comment: Ok, bueno, son errores de javscript, pero si no te importan a ti a mi menos :-)  En cuanto a tu problema, yo lo solucionaria cambiando esto: `<h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo_rechazo">Agregar Comentario Rechazo a  : </h5>` por esto `<h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo_rechazo">Agregar Comentario Rechazo a: <span id="nombre_rechazo"></span></h5>` por ejemplo.  Y luego cambiaria esto: `$("#titulo_rechazo").append(login);` por esto `$("#nombre_rechazo").html(login);` y yasta.  Así siempre se sobreescribe lo que haya y no tienes que preocuparte por el append